# Debugging page path in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm having some issues debugging a scenario, and wanted to test whether a specific page path exists. Is there a way to verify a Razor page exists (either before/after calling RedirectToPage)?

The specific scenario is trying to call `RedirectToPage` from inside a Post method in an mvc controller, to go to a Razor Page. However, instead of going to the page, it simply goes to the Get method (because the relative path to the page is incorrect).

I tried calling the following code to see if the page can be found at that path:

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
var pageLoader = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(PageLoader)) as PageLoader;
var pad = new PageActionDescriptor();
pad.RelativePath = "/Path/To/Razor/Page";
var page = await pageLoader.LoadAsync(pad);
```

But this just dies without any useful exception. I searched for other ways to find out if a page exists in code, but wasn't able to find a way.

EDIT: Ideally, I want something like this pseudocode

```
var isValidPath = ValidateRazorPage("Path/To/Page", "PageAreaGoesHere");
if(isValidPath)
   return RedirectToPage("Path/To/Page", new {area= "PageAreaGoesHere"});
else
  DoErrorHandlingToFigureOutIssue();
```

Comment: Generally a controller or page handler will `return RedirectToPage("./Path");`. You can use something like https://www.meziantou.net/list-all-routes-in-an-asp-net-core-application.htm to list the routes in your program.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Installing the nuget package for it fails ("NuGet Warning NU1213, <package> has a package type 'DotnetPlatform' that is not supported by project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get all valid paths as below:

inject `IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource>`  into your page/services

```
private readonly IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource> _endpoints;

public IndexModel(IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource> endpoints)
{
    
    _endpoints = endpoints; 
}
```

then you could get the paths with the codes below:

```
 var eps = _endpoints.SelectMany(es => es.Endpoints).OfType<RouteEndpoint>();
 var  paths=eps.Select(x=>x.RoutePattern.RawText).ToList();
```

It works well on myside:

[image]

If you want to seperate page route and area,you could try this line:

```
var partterns = eps.Select(x => x.RoutePattern.Defaults).ToList();
```

[image]